# Use wildcard in SQL Server full text search

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search

Assume I have these records in the `Languages` table

| ID | Title | Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | C# | Programming language development by Microsoft |
| 2 | Java | Programming language development by Sun Microsystems |

By using full text search in SQL Server, I want to search record by using wildcard in `CONTAINS` instead of `LIKE`

```
SELECT * 
FROM Languages 
WHERE Description LIKE '%icro%'
```

Seeking for help to write a query using `CONTAINS` that should output records similar as `LIKE` by using wildcard.

Thank you,

Comment: this link is help full for find your query need https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/search/query-with-full-text-search?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: You can only do a prefix search `CONTAINS(Description, '"Micro*"')` you need to start with the beginning of the word